# Plot the correct point on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to put the correct value of the point on x-axis not use the approximated number. For example, using pandas and matplotlib.

[image]

I would like to show these indexes:

```
index_plot = [4.4,7.6,11.0,14.2,17.4,20.8,24.0,27.1]
```

not

```
[0,5,10,15,20,25]
```

Is it possible to do?

```
plot_4.plot.line(logy=True, style=['+-','o-','.-','s-','x-'],grid=True,figsize=(10,6)).legend(title='algorithm', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), fontsize=12)

plt.xlabel('Current', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Beats per minute (BPM)', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an do:

```
ax = plot_4.plot.line(logy=True, style=['+-','o-','.-','s-','x-'],grid=True,figsize=(10,6)).legend(title='algorithm', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), fontsize=12)

ax.set_xticks(plot_4.index)
```